# mimeMap still does not display my svg

Tags: html, asp.net, svg, web-config

I am sorry if it is something novice or silly but this is my first time using a web.config file.

I have been dealing with the pleasure of godaddy not provide `svg` support by default. So I found some info on using a `web.config` file to inform the browser what to do with this file type.

Sources

1. [Link 1](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5445/what-is-a-webconfig-file?pc_split_value=4)
2. [Link 2](http://madskristensen.net/post/prepare-webconfig-for-html5-and-css3)
3. [Link 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815179)

---

I am able to get the file in the server without crashing everything. The website will still display instead of displaying a `500 (internal) error` but the `svg` still does nothing.

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="images/svg+xml" />
        <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="images/svg+xml" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I also put the file into the main root file on the server but no luck.

Live site if it helps: [Mobile app design](http://bestbenefitsclub.com/BBCM/login.html)

Comment: what client application/browser are you using and does it support svg files?

Comment: I am using the latest chrome, firefox, and IE which all display it incorrect. Godaddy by default doesn't include svg support so I followed their *easy* steps and now I am here. :/ The same website when I uploaded it onto my portfolio displays it correctly but not on the godadyd domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your mimeType is incorrect. Remove the "s" from the `images`:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
```

[reference, if you like documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/managing-your-configuration-settings/adding-ie-9-mime-types-to-iis)

Comment: My dear god you are a life saver! Finally this svg is displaying, woot!

Comment: just to add... I tried the above and it didn't work for me until I added this mysterious line above it: 
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />