# Link issue with MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a noob to ASP.NET and MVC so please bear with me, and thank you in advance for the help! --

I am trying to link to a KML file that is stored in the application's root and I cannot get it to work, see below:

```
function initCB(instance) {
            ge = instance;
            ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

            var href = 'http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example2.kml';
            var href2 = '~/cngKml.kml'
            google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href2, kmlFinishedLoading);

        }
```

It works when I point it to ther 'href' variable, but when I point it to the 'href2' variable it does not load anything.

The full index.cshtml is below:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "STI";
    string path = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/kml_example2.kml"));
}
<head>
    <title>CNG</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var ge;
        var placemark;
        var kmlObject;

        google.load("earth", "1", { "other_params": "sensor=false" });

        function init() {
            google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
        }

        function initCB(instance) {
            ge = instance;
            ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

            var href = 'http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example2.kml';
            var href2 = '@path';
            google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href2, kmlFinishedLoading);
        }

        function kmlFinishedLoading(obj) {
            kmlObject = obj;
            if (kmlObject) {
                if ('getFeatures' in kmlObject) {
                    kmlObject.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
                }
                ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
                if (kmlObject.getAbstractView())
                    ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
            }
        }

        function failureCB(errorCode) {
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

    </script>
</head>

@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}

<div id="gearth">
    <div id="map3d" style="width:960px; height:640px; align-self:center;"></div>
</div>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>STI</title>
        <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title"><a href="/">sti</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">

        Hello, <a class="username" href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">reecea</a>!
<form action="/Account/LogOff" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="J0EkwX2027gRZ-gDCvH1WMHGpGUnW-Sl2m3jEOpKw2684DUjjywYCFBQ9pPNfJ93pyJIZ9XH9HLMYdFNiVcHohtNsvKA1sIiKf3tL3EekGI1" />            <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
</form>    

                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Admin">Admin</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/Account/Manage">My Account</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">

    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>STI.</h1>
                <h2>CNG Stations Map</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>

            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">

<head>
    <title>CNG</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var ge;
        var placemark;
        var kmlObject;

        google.load("earth", "1", { "other_params": "sensor=false" });

        function init() {
            google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
        }

        function initCB(instance) {
            ge = instance;
            ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

            var href = 'http://code.google.com/apis/earth/documentation/samples/kml_example2.kml';
            var href2 = 'c:\\users\\reecea\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\CngStationMap\\CngStationMap\\kml_example2.kml';
            google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href2, kmlFinishedLoading);
        }

        function kmlFinishedLoading(obj) {
            kmlObject = obj;
            if (kmlObject) {
                if ('getFeatures' in kmlObject) {
                    kmlObject.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);
                }
                ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
                if (kmlObject.getAbstractView())
                    ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
            }
        }

        function failureCB(errorCode) {
        }

        google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

    </script>
</head>


<div id="gearth">
    <div id="map3d" style="width:960px; height:640px; align-self:center;"></div>
</div>


            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; 2014 - STI</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"9f6ba0e6c2d041d29dcc37b58bbb4ef4"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:54165/39bfdebe74ed45968bc576a815347820/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Web.Config File:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".kml"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"/>
    </staticContent>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing that:

```
var href2 = path;
```

to that:

```
var href2 = @path;
```

Without @ char it is treated as simple JS variable

By the way, if you define variable in C# and then use it in JavaScript, don't forget to use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`:

```
string path = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/cngKml.km"));
```

Comment: I made your suggested change and then added the mime type to the Web.Config file. Now google earth wont load at all :-(

What am I missing?

Comment: Use debugger to see what is the value of path vatiable

Comment: Have you modified only path variable? or something else?

Comment: Only the path variable. I used the debugger and its pointing to the correct file location.

Comment: Sorround @path with single quotes, like this: var href='@path';

Comment: That helped - the instance of Earth now loads but it is not loading the KML file still

Comment: I downloaded the kml example file that worked when it was linked and put it in the same directory to test if it my other KML file is corrupt. Still the same result - google earth initializes but doesnt load the KML file.

Comment: post your resulting html then

Comment: Posted (as an answer, sorry, I just realized i should have used pastebin)

Comment: So, do you see actual value of the href "var href2 = 'c:\\users\\reecea\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\CngStationMap\\CngStationMap\\kml_example2.kml';" You can't access it from the browser. you need to serve it from the webserver. See answer from MikeSmithDev: var href2 = '/cngKml.kml'

Comment: Gotcha, I will throw the file on a server then. I figured since it was in the project and project explorer it would work (temporarily, not as a permanent solution)

Thank you!!

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur the point is using that physical file path (the result of `Server.MapPath("~/cngKml.kml")` is *not* going to work as a valid `href` or `src` on a web server. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Try simply `var href2 = '/cngKml.kml'`

You can't use physical file paths for links (i.e. `Server.MapPath("~/cngKml.kml")`).

You can't use paths in client side code that the server needs to resolve either (i.e. `"~/anything"`).

You can't declare a variable in `C#` and then use it in JavaScript like you attempted. In the case above, you'd need to at least use `'@path'` (though it still wouldn't work).

Also, please verify that navigating to a `kml` file on your web server will even work, as unknown file types typically aren't served up by IIS. If this is a problem, you can fix with a web.config entry similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21707221/1810243/), [more ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965).

Comment: Why are you saying that can't use physical file paths for links? I tried and it works.

Comment: @Vitaliy because I can't imagine *any* scenario that would benefit from passing a server's physical file path to a client. I see plenty of beginners attempting to use that for image `src`, etc, and I'm trying to assist a self-described "noob to ASP.NET" by informing him that he should *not* do this. A relative or absolute url is correct. A physical file path is not. Please publish your code to a web-server and let me know if `Z:\somepath\cnhKml.kml` works for a client.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understood you correctly. I thought that you meant that code of MapPath won't work. Make sense, I agree with you. Your answer was correct actually.